# Error stating that undefined reference to putchar

Tags: c

The following is a snippet of the AES algorithm,

```
 void AESEncrypt(unsigned char * message, unsigned char * expandedKey, unsigned char * 
 encryptedMessage) {
 unsigned char state[16]; // Stores the first 16 bytes of original message

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    state[i] = message[i];
}
int numberOfRounds = 9;

AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey); 

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRounds; i++) {
    Round(state, expandedKey + (16 * (i+1)));
}

FinalRound(state, expandedKey + 160);


for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    encryptedMessage[i] = state[i];

}
```

Now when I try to call this function,

```
AESEncrypt(paddedMessage+i, expandedKey, encryptedMessage+i);
```

I get an error stating that,

```
error: undefined reference to "putchar".
```

The code does not have putchar but still it gives me the error. I dont know why.

Please help!!

Comment: you are not linking with the standard library

Comment: Somewhere there is a call to putchar. To find out where simply write dummy putchar, set the breakpoint and see who did call it.

Comment: Please post the complete error message. It tells you which module has this unresolved reference.

Comment: @thebusybee "write dummy putchar"

Comment: Since `putchar(c)` is documented to be equivalent to `putc(c, stdout)`, and `putc()` is permitted to be implemented as a macro, the problem may be that `stdio.h` has not been included in one of the TUs that references `putchar()` (which I conclude is also permitted to be a macro).  That might itself come with some attending warnings about calling undeclared functions.  That seems more likely to me than a failure to link against the C standard library, which I would expect to produce a whole slew of link errors for most programs, not just the one.

Comment: The reason for this error is that the code is missing `#include <stdio.h>`. Or alternatively that the compiler libs are corrupt or incorrectly installed. That's it.

Comment: @thebusybee read the rest of the comment

Comment: Yes, i did not include stdio.h but that is because that lib is not supported by the embedded platform that I am using that is VexRisc. I am looking for an alternative for putchar. are there any other .h files that support putchar and memstr?

Comment: I have posted exactly where I got the error in the following link. If you guys would like to check, click on the link below,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704961/undefined-reference-to-putchar