# undefined reference to putchar

Tags: c, aes

This is a code snippet,

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenofPaddedMessage; i += 16) {  //undefined reference to putchar
    unsigned char state[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        state[i] = paddedMessage[i];
    }
    int numberOfRounds = 9;

    AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey); 

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRounds; i++) {
        Round(state, expandedKey + (16 * (i+1)));
    }

    FinalRound(state, expandedKey + 160);


    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        encryptedMessage[i] = state[i];

    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < lenofPaddedMessage; i++) {
    printf("%5X",(int)encryptedMessage[i]);
}
```

I am getting the error for the for loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenofPaddedMessage; i += 16) //undefined reference to putchar.
```

I have not used putchar but still I am getting the error in the for statement. Is there any alternative to the for loop so that the logic of my code does not change and the putchar function is not implicitly called?

I dont want putchar as the target platform that I am using does not support putchar.

Comment: Well, that doesn't make much sense. Do you think you can narrow down the problem a little more? Please refer to [mre] for guidance. What's the smallest possible program, which still reproduces the error?

Comment: You have `printf()` that calls `putchar()` in many implementations. Why do you think is the line with the for loop the reason? -- BTW, please indent your code properly, it is too hard to read.

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdio.h>` in the code? You need that anyway for the `printf` call.

Comment: Please try to make a [mcve] and show the verbatim error log.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? 
 Here's the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69677588/error-stating-that-undefined-reference-to-putchar)

Comment: yes but the accurate spot where the error was occurring was not clearly mentioned. Here I have clearly mentioned that the for loop is where the putchar error is occuring

Comment: is there a way to write an if statement for the the for loop,

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < lenofPaddedMessage; i += 16)

Comment: If you comment out the `printf` calls, do you still get the same undefined reference to `putchar`?

Comment: Well lets close the old one as dupe to this one rather than the other way around, since this one is better phrased. I've closed the old one.

Comment: Anyway, embedded systems platforms need not support `stdio.h`. But if they do, they need to support all of it. So you can't have `printf` but not `putchar` or the library is non-compliant.

Comment: @Lundin Is there a reference for that "all-or-nothing" thing for freestanding implementations?

Comment: @IanAbbott I guess not, but it's strange to partially implement a library and claim to be compliant. There may be something in chapter 7 stating it. The minimum required libs are defined in 4/6.

Comment: @IanAbbott Actually 7.1.3 might be it: "Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause"

Comment: @Lundin OTOH, 4 para 6 says a conforming freestanding implementation only needs to accept strictly conforming programs that use certain headers (as listed in 4. Conformance paragraph 6). It could be argued that anything in other hosted implementation standard headers is an extension for freestanding implementations, but IANALL.

Comment: There is not support for printf either @Lundin